# How is it possible for a function with an argument int& to handle a variable of a type int**?

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax

How is it possible for a function with an argument `int&` to handle a variable of type `int**`?

For example, I have the regular swap function and it works when I pass it variables from a an array of pointers. How is that it doesn't cause a type mismatch error? since swap should receive only `int` not `int**`.

```
void swap(int& a, int& b);
const int SIZE = 6;
int main(){

    int arr[SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    int*pointers[SIZE];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
        pointers[i] = &arr[i];
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        swap(pointers[i], pointers[i + 1]);
}


void swap(int& a, int& b){
    int t;
    t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
```

Comment: Please post an MCVE.

Comment: Please show us the code which calls `swap()`.

Comment: Anyway, are you aware of `std::swap`? Also, corrected tags as references are distinctly *not* C.

Comment: It isn't possible. My guess is that you have a rogue `using namespace std;` somewhere, so that your code is calling `std::swap` instead of your partial reinvention of it.

Comment: Now post an example that you tried to compile. What you posted has missing semicolons, among other things.

Comment: Rename `swap` to `hobbitses` and try to compile again.

Comment: Well, you added the semicolons but obviously still did not try compiling it (`swap` is used before declaration).

Comment: When you place a prototype for your `swap` (or the function) before you call it, you actually get the error message about inompatible types you were expecting.

Comment: @interjay originally the swap is inside a lot of irrelevant code that's why I tried to write that simple use of it but it looks like I get an error now this time...

Comment: @kuhaku Writing a simple example is great (and expected here), as long as you test that the example actually demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @molbdnilo is right. looks like I was using the library swap and not my function...

Comment: Moral of the story? Don't `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I'm kind of a noob, what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already function in the standard called `swap`, it lives in `namespace std` and is defined for everything:

```
// simplification
namespace std {
    template <typename T>
    void swap(T&, T&) { .. }
}
```

You provide your own version, which doesn't conflict since it's in a different namespace (and isn't a template):

```
void swap(int&, int&) { .. }
```

Normally, there would be no contention and what's going on would be obvious:

```
swap(i1, i2);                      // fine, calls yours
std::swap(c1, c2);                 // fine, calls std::swap<char>
swap(c1, c2);                      // error: can't convert char to int&
swap(pointers[i], pointers[i+1]);  // error: can't convert int* to int&
```

But somewhere in your code, you have:

```
using namespace std;
```

That brings in `std::swap` into the global namespace - and now your `swap` just acts as an overload of that one - one which is preferred for `int&`:

```
swap(i1, i2);                      // fine, calls yours
swap(c1, c2);                      // fine, calls std::swap<char>
swap(pointers[i], pointers[i+1]);  // fine, calls std::swap<int*>
```

That's why it works. It's not that somehow you somehow allowed `int*` to be converted to `int&` - it's that you're silently calling an entirely different function than the one you thought you were. Moral of the story: avoid `using namespace std;` - it'll make what your code is doing that much clearer.